# MVC4 Dialog box handing using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I am developing application using MVC4,
Here I want to load a partial view (containing filled dropdown list) in dialog box and want to send use selected value to controller.

I tried below code but it is giving me error "0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".
I am not getting dialog box in output.

**Partial View Containing dropdown :**

```
@model InterviewAssistant.Models.CommonWrapper



@if (Model.tech != null && Model.tech.Count() > 0)
{
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Select Technology">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Select the technology</p>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedTrackId)
     @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.SelectedTechId,
            new SelectList(Model.tech, "TechId", "TechName"),
            string.Empty
            )
        </div>
}
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


            $("#fresh").click(function () {

                InitializeDialog($("#my-dialog"));


                $("#my-dialog").dialog("open");
            });



            //Method to Initialize the DialogBox
            function InitializeDialog($element) {

                //alert("Hi");

                $element.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {

                        $(this).load("/Home/SelectTrack");
                    },

                    close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }

                });

            }
        });
```

**Controller Code :**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SelectTrack(int? selectedTrackId)
        {
            CommonWrapper wrapper = new CommonWrapper();
            wrapper.tech = new List<TechModel>();

            if (selectedTrackId.HasValue)
            {
                wrapper.tech = (from s in CommonWrapper.GetTechnology()
                                where s.TrackId == selectedTrackId
                                orderby s.TechName
                                select s).ToList();
            }


            return PartialView("TechnologyDialog",wrapper);

        }
```

Geting error on $element.dialog stmt.
Can anybody please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Geting error on $element.dialog statement

Comment: I think you need parenthesis.  $(element).dialog...